# Asp.net idea on how chat box logic works?

Tags: asp.net, timer, triggers, updatepanel, postback

currently I have a chat box on asp.net webform

What I am using now is scriptmanager 
Timer,  updatepanel, and trigger
Updatepanel is set to conditional.
Trigger set with timer I'd.

Every few seconds.  The timer runs timer_tick and checks the sql database for new message and update the updatepanel.

My problem is the updatepanel gets refreshed every few seconds regardless of if there is new messages.

In the code behind, How do I make it only postback if a conditional is made.  Is it because my trigger is set to the timer?   I have tested it.  Even if the timer method is completely empty.  It still updates the updatepanel.

Is there any way in the timer method to force no postback?

Is it possible to make a client side thread to check the chat message database then update the updatepanel if a conditional is made?

Thanks.

The problem is regardless if i put a conditional or not.. Timer1_Tick() always refreshes the updatepanel.
In the code behind

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (All_Panel.Enabled)
    {
        SQL DB = new SQL();
        if (DB.IsCustomerOnline())
        {
            SessionID = DB.GetSessionID();
            if (SessionID.CompareTo("") != 0)
            {
                if (!C_BT_Message.Enabled)
                {
                    DB.AddNewMessage(Request.UserHostAddress, "Connected Customer: " + SessionID, SessionID, "Admin");
                    C_BT_Message.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                C_BT_Message.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        List<string> li = DB.GetMessages(DB.GetSessionID());

        if (TotalRow != li.Count && li.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string s in li)
                {
                    // CreateDiv(s, "ForUser");

                    CreateDiv(GetDate(s) + "<br />" + GetMessage(s), GetIdentity(s).CompareTo("Customer") == 0 ? "ForUser" : "ForAdmin");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
        }
        TotalRow = li.Count;
    }

}
```

Below is the aspx.

```
          <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000"  OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
     </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>
       <div id="chat_box" runat="server" class="C_chat">
        <div id="C_ChatAdmin" runat="server" class ="C_ChatMessage">

        </div>
       </div>
      </ContentTemplate>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried

Comment: No one knows?  is there any way in timer_tick() method to force no postback?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out.  I made a dummy updatepanel.  It is invisible.  I put the trigger in it.  And calls the other updatepanel if the conditional is met by doing updatepanel.update().  The problem with this somehow now is.  It clears all my data on the panel waits for 2 seconds then repopulate.  I really need somehow to keep the state of my previous added div into C_chatAdmin.  Somehow enableviewstate.  But dynamic added controls are stateless base on my research..  it does repopulate every time.

The 2 seconds page clears then repopulate is my main problem now.